# create report for checking contact and usera are available for one user in salesforce

Tags: reporting, salesforce-id, custom-report-type, reports-api, joined-reports

There are contact and users available in salesforce with same user. For contact and users email address will be same.
I need to verify in report that all the users have contact created. 
Could you please assist me how to create a report in salesforce ?

Regards,
Anjana

Answer (score 1):

Refer [Build Reports in Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=reports_builder_editing.htm&type=0&language=en_US&release=208.11) and [Reports and Dashboard Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/reports_dashboards) to create reports

Let me know if you face any other issue.